# How to differentiate the calls made by the applications and the users(manually)?

Tags: android

In my application I want to warn the users when a call/text is being made by an application.

An application is attempting a call without user intervention.. and a user himself is attempting a call by dialling a number... I want to warn the user ONLY in the first scenario i.e., when an application tries to make a call.

Comment: little bit more explain about you question.

Comment: okay fine... i want to differentiate among the following scenarios...  an application is attempting a call without user intervention.. and a user himself is attempting a call by dialling a number... i want to warn the user ONLY in the first scenario i.e., when an application tries to make a call.. hope you got it now.. :)